# spark only run on one machine

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I deploy a spark cluster with three machines named A B C, and an HDFS cluster is deployed on the three machines too.

When I submit a spark task using hdfs as input on the A or B or C machine, only one machine is running. It looks likes below:

[image]

But when I submit the same spark task to other machine, all three machines are running. It looks likes below:

[image]

I have already set the `dfs.replication` to 3 in hdfs-site.xml, so these three machines all should have the full data of input file.  Why does only one machine run the spark task?

Comment: perhaps the one machine that makes it work is the master?

Comment: At the first picture, the master is fdc-aa02, and I submit task at fdc-aa01.

Comment: Good use of paint.

Comment: then what is the question? if you don't submit the task to the master, it will not run on the cluster, but only on the node to which you submitted the task

Comment: Try specify the master url in all cases.
 what is --master in your case ?

Comment: I submit task to the cluster, but only run task on one node when I submit task on one machine of this cluster.

Comment: Yes, I have already specify the master url, the fdc-aa02 is master